# syntax to loop through docs send from express router and use it to plot chart js

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, chart.js

I am starting to learn node js (express js). I am trying to plot a chart using data sent from the mongo db using mongoose....I would want to loop the docs sent from the database to be used in ploting the data. I had tried using fetch api but it failed due to Passport req.user (it didn't recognize user )
here is my code. I will appreciate for any help and leads.

```html
router.get('/mychart', loggedInYes, function (req, res, next) {
  Products.find({user:req.user._id},function (err,docs) {
    if (err)
      return err;
      res.render('user/mychart',{docs:docs});
    
    });
 });
```

and here is the chart js where I would want to use Docs

```html
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
          labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
          datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [{
                {#
                  each docs
                }
              } {
                {
                  this.docs.yearofbirth
                }
              } {
              {
                /each}}],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                  ],
                  borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                  ],
                  borderWidth: 1
              }]
            },
            options: {
              scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                  ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                  }
                }]
              }
            }
          });
</script>
```

The problem is how to loop through the data....data: [{
                {#
                  each docs
                }
              } {
                {
                  this.docs.yearofbirth
                }
              } {
              {
                /each}}],

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by including the credentials objects in the client hbs file. It worked

```html
fetch('/api/foo', {credentials: 'include'})
```